# Resizing a UIView hides subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, nslayoutconstraint

I have a view controller with a view that doesn't fill the screen and has transparency around the edges. In said view I have a tableview, some buttons and a text field.

I have all of the controls attached to the bottom of the view with constraints and the tableview attached to the top.

Everything resizes fine when the device is put in landscape/portrait mode, but when I manually resize it when the keyboard appears, the bottom of the view just moves up and covers the lowest elements.

Resizing/animation code:

```
- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notification {

    //Stuff to get keyboard frames

    void (^animations)() = ^() {
        CGRect mainViewFrame = self.mainView.frame;

        CGRect tableViewFrame = self.tableView.frame;

        tableViewFrame.size.height = tableViewFrame.size.height - 50;
        mainViewFrame.size.height = mainViewFrame.size.height - 50;

        CGFloat paddingOffset = self.view.frame.size.height - self.mainView.frame.origin.y - self.mainView.frame.size.height;

        mainViewFrame.origin.y = (mainViewFrame.origin.y - keyboardEndFrame.size.height + paddingOffset - 8);

        self.mainView.frame = mainViewFrame;

        [self.tableView setNeedsLayout];
        [self.mainView setNeedsLayout];
    };

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration
                          delay:0.0
                        options:(animationCurve << 16)
                     animations:animations
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         if (finished) {
                             NSLog(@"Finished animating");
                             self.acceptBottomConstraint.constant = 5;
                             self.cancelBottomConstraint.constant = 5;
                         }
                     }];
}
```

This is my UI in the Storyboard:

[image: IB Image]

This is what it looks like after resizing:

[image: Broken UI in device]

Comment: you should your UIView (Container) in an UIScrollView to be able set it on top of keyboard :)

Comment: Why are you changing the table frame too? If the layout is fully defined, optimally you would only need to update the size of the view, and all of its subviews should respond accordingly.

Comment: Changing the table frame doesn't actually do anything, it's in there because I was trying as many different things as possible to see what works